# Error using Spring namespace configuration

Tags: java, spring

I am a Spring novice trying to inject data from a properties file into a bean. I am using Spring version 2.5.6. My xml file is as follows

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

 <beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
          xmlns:util = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
          xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id = "t" class = "com.spring.readingpropertiesfile.Drivers">
      <property name = "test">
      <util.properties location = "classpath:com/spring/readingpropertiesfile/Default.properties">
      </util.properties>
      </property>
   </bean>

 </beans>
```

I am trying to read from file Default.properties which is in package com.spring.readingpropertiesfile

When I run, I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 9 in XML document from class path resource [com/spring/readingpropertiesfile/beans.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 73; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.spring.readingpropertiesfile.Client.main(Client.java:8)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 73; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1900)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:740)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    ... 14 more
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For starters, you're explicitly using the 3.0 namespace, and 5.0 is almost out. What is your reason for mixing XML configuration in with Spring Boot?

Comment: <beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
          xmlns:util = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
          xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-5.0.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-5.0.xsd">

Comment: I get the same error if I use 5.0 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to `xsi:schemaLocation` from `xmlns:schemaLocation`,

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
      xmlns:util = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
      xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```

### Concrete Example

Here is a concrete example,

#### MyDriver - class which has the attributes

```
package abc.service;

public class MyDriver {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

#### beans.xml - file where yu declare the beans

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:example/my.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDriver"
          class="abc.service.MyDriver">

        <property name="username" value="${my.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${my.password}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

#### my.properties - file which contains the properties

The properties file is located under `resources/example` folder

```
my.username=hello
my.password=there
```

#### Project Layout

```
example-project
|_ src
  |_ main
    |_ java
      |_ service
        |_ abc
          |_ MyDriver.java
  |_ resources
    |_ example
      |_ my.properties
  |_ webapp
    |_ WEB-INF
      |_ beans.xml
      |_ web.xml
```

Comment: If i try that, I get this error cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'util.properties'. One of '{"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":meta, 
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, 
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":idref, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":value, 
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":null,

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned in my post. Updated my post. Is it something like this you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @Indra Basak, if I try the value tag the code the code takes the value classpath as key and the string that follows the : as value. But what I want is to be able to read from the file.

Comment: Are you trying to read from the file directly or are you let Spring do the leg work?

Comment: i am trying to let Spring read the com/spring/readingpropertiesfile/Default.properties file and assign them to a  Properties object

Comment: Updated my post. Try it again.

Comment: This time I am getting  Invalid bean definition with name 't' defined in class path resource [com/spring/readingpropertiesfile/beans.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'test.prop'

Comment: Updated my posting with a concrete example.